# Can't find package bacula

Tags: apt

I want to configure a backup system using bacula. The problem I ran into is, when trying to install bacula by `sudo apt install bacula`, I always get the answer

```
:~$ sudo apt install bacula
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
E: Paket bacula kann nicht gefunden werden.
```

> E: Package bacula can not be found    *[translated online]*

I thought bacula would be a very popular software and I would like to use it.

Does someone know why I get this message and how I could acomplish it?

Many thanks in advice.

Comment: Do you have the universe repository enabled?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You didn't tell us your release, but https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=bacula shows it's available and in 'universe' - do you have it (universe repository) enabled?

Comment: Thank you very much for the friendly welcome message! No I think I havent't enabled universe. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bacula` is available only in [*universe* repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=bacula), you need to enable it first

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```

then you're ready to go with

```
sudo apt-get install bacula
```